# How can I chain asynchronous NSURLConnections?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

What would be the most appropriate way to chain asynchronous NSURLConnections? For example, I need to register a user with a web service. The workflow would be as follows:
Get Register Token => Use token to Register => Get Login Token => Use token to Login.

I know how to create an asynchronous NSURLConnection, but I'm unsure how to make sure the previous connection has finished before moving on. I know I can achieve this using `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest` but I don't like my main thread being blocked while these chained requests happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did EXACTLYA this when we built our first version of SignMeOut for iPhone. We created a subclass of NSUrlconnection and gave it an identifying tag do in the connectionDidFinish you would be able to use a simple switch/case with an enum. Works great - you can see the whole flow and example and code in our blog

http://www.isignmeout.com/multiple-nsurlconnections-viewcontroller/

**UPDATE**

I've modified the NSURLConnection subclass into a much simpler Category. Most of the usage is the same but cleaner using the same class

https://github.com/Shein/Categories

Comment: Superb! Thanks so much for taking the time to post this.

Comment: Glad it's useful to others :) let me know how it work out for you

Comment: Just as an update, tried this earlier, works great! Perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at `connectionDidFinishLoading` to start another asynchronous connection. For the conditions as to which connection ended, you can keep references to the connections in case other connections are also expected to finish(probably not needed in your case). Make your class follow the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and fire the appropriate connections in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` delegate method. You can also use the `connectionDidReceiveData:` method to check for credentials, etc received from the service. Go through the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) too.

Comment: Great thanks! How would you recommended splitting these methods up? For example I have two main scenarios. 1) User is registering, which will need the four conditions stated above, 2) user is logging in in which we will only need the last two connections. Would `BOOL isRegistering` iVar or something be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You have different options:

- create a queue using a mutable array or dictionary
- create an NSOperationQueue kind of easy if you use it in combination
  with the new only ios5 API for NSUrlConnection
- third parties lib such as AFNetworking
- Block GCD grouping them (hard for NSRunLoop reasons, pay attention in wich thread the connection is running in)

Comment: OK great. Nice to know all the options!